# Textbox or textfield that can change to outlined in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, textfield

Does C# have a similar Textfield/Textbox that can change when active similar to the one. Wanted to implement textbox in WPF C# but cannot find the textbox type.

https://mui.com/components/text-fields/

[image]

When not active, it will be on left, when active, it is on the right.

Comment: You must override the ControlTemplate of the TextBox and use a Trigger to handle the layout if IsKeyboardFocusWithin returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the opensource library [MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit). There is a control similar to this one.

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextFieldTextBox}"/>
```

[image]